# iphone - xmpp offline message timestamp lead the chat list disorder

Tags: ios, time, timezone, xmpp

I'm trying to build a Chat app using XMPP. It works fine. However, I found when I got the offline message from other people, my chat list became disorder. That's because the offline messages' timestamps are stored by server time and the server time is different from my device's time. So could you tell me how to adjust time I got from server or other solutions to solve this problem, very thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have the same question as me, I found the answer and share with you  my solution here. In XMPP, we have two extension : XEP-0202 XMPPAutoTime and XEP-0136 XMPPMessageArchiving.

When we use XMPPMessageArchiving in our appDelegate, the messages (no matter online or offline) will store to core data. If the message is offline message, the timestamp will be server's time. And some devices' clocks may differ from server's. We can use the XMPPAutoTime to deal with the delay between device's clock and sever's clock.

In XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.m can find a function called

```
 - (void)archiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message outgoing:(BOOL)isOutgoing xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)xmppStream
```

and find the following code in this function :

```
        if (timestamp)
            archivedMessage.timestamp = timestamp;
        else
            archivedMessage.timestamp = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

Here, those codes are deal with the message timestamp stored to core data.We adjust the offline message timestamp by using "XMPPAutoTime"

```
        if (timestamp){
            NSTimeInterval timeDiffer = [[self appDelegate].xmppAutoTime timeDifference];
            timestamp = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval: - timeDiffer sinceDate:timestamp];
            archivedMessage.timestamp = timestamp;

        }
        else
            archivedMessage.timestamp = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

That's work for me. (Of course you have to import AppDelegate and set xmppAutoTime in AppDelegate)

Comment: @LucaDavanzo you need wait for some seconds to XMPPAuatoTime can get timeDifference. You can check it by implement `func xmppAutoTime(sender: XMPPAutoTime!, didUpdateTimeDifference timeDifference: NSTimeInterval)` of `XMPPAutoTimeDelegate`

Answer (score 2):

I too faced offline time zone issue with XMPP. My issue is when i am trying to retrieve from database(CoreData) getting 10min fast time for first time when i got message from another user if i be in offline.That issue is resolved by below code
In XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.m
You can find

> ```
> - (void)archiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message outgoing:(BOOL)isOutgoing xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)xmppStream
> ```

and find the following code in this function

> ```
>    if (timestamp)
>         archivedMessage.timestamp = timestamp;
>     else
>         archivedMessage.timestamp = [[NSDate alloc] init];
> ```

Replace above code with below code

> ```
>      if (timestamp)
>         {
>             NSDate *deviceTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
>             NSTimeInterval timeInterval=[deviceTime timeIntervalSinceDate:timestamp];
>             timestamp=[NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:timeInterval sinceDate:timestamp];
>             archivedMessage.timestamp = timestamp;
>         }
>         else
>             archivedMessage.timestamp = [[NSDate alloc] init];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to keep the user's items in sync. What I did was keeping the time difference between the server and the client.

Before being able to send data to the server, the client requests the timestamp to the server. Then it keeps the time offset. Here's my code (responseObject is a dictionary with the data fetched from the server).

```
     NSTimeInterval serverTimestamp = [[responseObject valueForKey:@"timestamp"] unsignedIntegerValue];
     NSTimeInterval appTimestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
     [self setServerTimeOffset:(serverTimestamp - appTimestamp)];
```

Then, when I make a request, I calculate the server timestamp :

```
- (NSDate *)serverDate {
    return [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:_serverTimeOffset];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that in XMPP has some extensions can use. The way is similar to your's and it works well.